# "fromString" method on case classes extending a sealed trait

Tags: scala, case-class, sealed

Is there an idiomatic way of generating something like a `fromString` method on a `sealed trait` for use with `case classes`?

For example, something like:

```
sealed trait ExampleEnum {def id: Any}

final case class One(first: String) extends ExampleEnum{ override def id = first}
final case class Two(first: String, second: String) extends ExampleEnum { override def id = (first, second) }
```

Where should `def fromString(s: String): ExampleEnum` exist? A companion `object` for the `sealed trait`? Something else? It feels like this "de-serialization" pattern would be something that exists or has a standard approach that would be found in existing packages.

Comment: A companion object for the sealed trait

Answer (score 1):

Use a companion object for the sealed trait.